# Asp.net MVC, Pass Array to Controller From View Without Using Ajax

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am Using asp.net mvc 5. I want to pass array of string from view to controller without using Ajax. Can Anyone help?

This is the controller, value is to be gotten in packagelist[]

```
public ActionResult Create(Business business, string loc, string serv, string[] packagelist)
{
    try
    {               
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var a = locationIds;
            business.ServiceId = db.Services.Where(x => x.Title ==serv).Select(x => x.Id).SingleOrDefault();
            business.LocationId = db.Locations.Where(x => (x.Title + " (" + x.State + "), " + x.PostalCode)==loc).Select(x => x.Id).SingleOrDefault();       
            db.Businesses.Add(business);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        else
        {
            foreach(var error in ModelState.Values)
            {
                foreach(var er in error.Errors)
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", er.Exception.ToString());
                }
            }
            ViewData["Packages"] = db.BusinessPackages.Select(x => new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = x.Package,
            });
            return View(business);
        }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", ex);
        return View(business);
    }
}
```

Have created an hidden input on view

```
<input type="hidden" name="packagelist" id="packagelist" value="" />
```

Then set the value of this hidden field via this function

```
$("#theform").submit(function (e) {                   
    e.preventDefault();                     
    var locdiv=$("#maindiv");
    var locations = locdiv.children();
    var loc = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++)
    {                         
        loc.push(locations.eq(i).text());                          
    }
    // SaveLocations(loc);
    $("#packagelist").val(loc);
    $("#theform").submit();
```

Now main problem is that when I set value of the input via Jquery and submit it to the controller, controller is considering the array of values as single value.

Comment: Post ur model to controller action using form submit.

Comment: I have created an <input type="hidden" value=""/> but not getting to the point how to set value as an array to this

Comment: @IkramKhan post some code to explain better

Comment: I have posted the complete code

Comment: what about making packageList variable a string and just doing string.split and splitting it into an array.

Comment: Your code is not making sense. What are the elements in your element with `id="maindiv"` (show the view). And why are you assigning them to an javascript array? If you want to bind values to `string[] packagelist` then you need multiple inputs with `name="packagelist"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use cookies.

In JS,
document.cookie = "CookiesName=" + value + "; " + "365;path=/";

In Controller,
var data = Request.Cookies["CookiesName"]

Answer (score 1):

To receive an array as param in controller, your inputs need specific naming

```
<input type="hidden" name="packagelist[0]" id="packagelist_0_" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="packagelist[1]" id="packagelist_1_" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="packagelist[2]" id="packagelist_2_" value="" />
...
<input type="hidden" name="packagelist[x]" id="packagelist_x_" value="" />
```